# to make large SSRS report printable

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am having issue while printing report from SSRS. I can export to Excel. This is big layout report. Can you please provide any suggestion to make it printable.

Comment: What about using two (or more) lines for the data instead of trying to cram it all into one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend exporting, then in excel you can see the print boundaries after opening and closing the print menu. You can then adjust the size of the columns to allow it to fit within a single page width. Beyond that, changing font size or scaling the data in the print menu. I'd need more details to give a more exact answer.

Comment: Thanks JHarper, Yes I think only way to export into excel and then go form there. But because this is wide report , I need to make it printable

Answer (score 0):

This would really depend on how "big" the layout of your report is.

You want to determine what is the biggest paper size you are able to print on, then you can set the dimensions of the report to correspond with the size. Easiest way is to right click outside of the report body and click "Report Properties". You can pick your **orientation**, **paper size** and the **margins**.

When I have a report with a good number of columns that needs to be printed, I typically set the paper size as **Letter (W11 x H8.5)**, orientation of the report to **Landscape**, set left and right margins to **.25**. This means the max width of the report cannot exceed **10.5 in.** (W11 - .5 (left and right margin combined)). To verify this, go to **Properties** window (F4), on the very top of the window there is a dropdown that highlights which properties you are adjusting, make sure it's selected to **Body**. With this example, the size of the body should have a width not exceeding **10.5 in.**.

When you **Preview** the report, in the toolbar there is a **Print Layout** icon, this will show you what your report will look like when it's printed.

If it still doesn't print nicely despite setting all the size correctly, I would recommend removing some columns.